# How to add D3 tooltips

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

Currently I am looking in to D3 sample trying to alter it to add tooltips https://plnkr.co/edit/stHnntCknDUs0Xw6MlQ2?p=preview but cant manage it myself.

I want to add tooltip and pointers to this the way like it is done here http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html

```
//Add tooltips 
     // Define the div for the tooltip
      var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
          .attr("class", "tooltip")             
          .style("opacity", 0);

      // Add the scatterplot
    countryEnter.selectAll("dot")   
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
        .attr("r", 5)       
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.stat); })      
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.date)   
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
```

Just cant get it working

Comment: did my answer solve your problem ??

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the hover on the wrong element. You are putting them on the dots (which don't exist as in your data you as you have no `date` attribute).

What I have done is place them on the path like so :

```
 countryEnter.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
       .on("mouseover", function(d) {   
          console.log(d)
            divTooltip.transition()     
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
            .innerHTML(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close) 

            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            divTooltip.transition()     
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
```

But I still get the error `formatTime` is not defined. But the problem is solved on getting the tooltip to be viewed. So solving the rest shouldn't be difficult :)

Updated plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/zQY0Wen1plIMuwOMq3PE?p=preview